# Sendmail - setting the from address?

Tags: linux, email, php, sendmail

I've just set up sendmail to send emails from joe@javawag.com from within PHP (javawag.com is my domain and I have google apps mail set up on it). The problem is, when I read the mail I receive, it says "joe@javawag.dyndns.org"... this is what javawag.com resolves to (javawag.com -> javawag.dyndns.org -> [my dynamic ip address, changeable]). I'd like to have it show up as javawag.com however, so does anyone know how to do that?

BTW, I'm setting the from: header to joe@javawag.com, but it still shows as joe@javawag.dyndns.org (this also means it falls into my spam folder!)

- Joe

Comment: Why would it get marked as spam for _that_?

Comment: or perhaps it's because the subject and/or body were near enough blank... but it was marked as spam!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`MASQUERADE_AS`](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/masquerading_relaying.html#MASQUERADE_AS) feature in your `sendmail.mc` file:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`javawag.com')
```

Make sure `javawag.com` is listed as a local domain (although you presumably already do that).

You may also need `` FEATURE(`allmasquerade') `` and/or `` FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope') ``, depending on your setup; see [the `sendmail` documentation](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/features.html) for more information.

Comment: this makes sense, trying it now :D

Comment: hey, that's only gone and worked! thanks a lot for your help!